# Use time to equalize the game updates

Tags: c#, xna

I'm trying to set the FPS cap of my XNA game to 90, now it is set, the game go at an amazing speed, even if i multiply the speed with `(float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds`.
Can you help me figuring out why it isn't working? I see all the others are running that fine but mine won't work.

So this is my `Player` class(big enough):

update method:

```
public void Update(GameTime gameTime, MouseState mouse, KeyboardState keyboard, GamePadState gamepad, KeyboardState oldKeyboard)
{
    m_align = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds / 1000; 
    move(gameTime, mouse, keyboard, gamepad); //On gere le déplacement du joueur

    //ACTIONS POSSIBLES
    if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space)) //TIR
    {
       m_weapon[m_activeWeapon].Shoot(ref GameMain.Bullets, m_hitbox, m_direction);
    }
    else if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.R) && oldKeyboard.IsKeyUp(Keys.R)) //RECHARGEMENT DE L'ARME ACTIVE
    {
        m_weapon[m_activeWeapon].reload();
    }

    if (keyboard.IsKeyUp(Keys.Z) //Si on ne se déplace 
        && keyboard.IsKeyUp(Keys.S)
        && keyboard.IsKeyUp(Keys.Q) 
        && keyboard.IsKeyUp(Keys.D))
    {
       this.FrameColumn = 1;
    }

    if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.H))
    {
        m_hp--;
        if (m_hp < 0)
        {
            m_hp = 0;
        }
    }
```

move method:

```
public void move(GameTime gameTime, MouseState mouse, KeyboardState keyboard, GamePadState gamepad)
{
    if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Z) || gamepad.DPad.Up == ButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        m_position.Y -= m_speed * m_align;
        if (inScreen() != true || tileCollision() == true) //Si le déplacement est illégal
        {
            m_position.Y += m_speed * m_align;
            FrameColumn = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            m_direction = Direction.Up;
            Animate();
            WalkSound();
        }
    }
    else if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.S) || gamepad.DPad.Down == ButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        m_position.Y += m_speed * m_align;
        if (inScreen() != true || tileCollision() == true) //Si le déplacement est illégal
        {
            m_position.Y -= m_speed * m_align;
            FrameColumn = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            m_direction = Direction.Down;
            Animate();
            WalkSound();
        }
    }
    else if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Q) || gamepad.DPad.Left == ButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        m_position.X -= m_speed * m_align;
        if (inScreen() != true || tileCollision() == true) //Si le déplacement est illégal
        {
            m_position.X += m_speed * m_align;
            FrameColumn = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            m_direction = Direction.Left;
            Animate();
            WalkSound();
        }
    }
    else if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.D) || gamepad.DPad.Right == ButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        m_position.X += m_speed * m_align;
        if (inScreen() != true || tileCollision() == true) //Si le déplacement est illégal
        {
            m_position.X -= m_speed * m_align;
            FrameColumn = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            m_direction = Direction.Right;
            Animate();
            WalkSound();
        }
    }
    m_hitbox.X = (int)m_position.X;
    m_hitbox.Y = (int)m_position.Y;
}
```

Attributes :

```
//Attributs
public Vector2 m_position;
public Rectangle m_hitbox;
Direction m_direction;
int m_speed = 3;
float m_align; //Variable d'alignement du temps

string m_name;
int m_hp;
Weapon[] m_weapon;
int m_activeWeapon;

int FrameLine;
int FrameColumn;
int animationSpeed;
SpriteEffects Effect;
int Timer; //animation frames

int SoundTimer; //Son bruit de pas
bool SoundSteps; //Son bruit de pas
```

Comment: instead of using TotalMilliseconds / 1000, you could use TotalSeconds. Dont' have a solution for your problem though. Havent been able to test (@ work)

Answer (score 1):

By default your update and draw methods are limited to 60 calls per second. to change this add or change to this:

```
Game.IsFixedTimeStep = false;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.isfixedtimestep.aspx